# Trouble getting headroom.js to work on my site

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add headroom.js (http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/) to my portfolio website and am having trouble getting it to work.

I have downloaded headroom.min.js and added it to my site in the js folder I created.  I have not altered the code at all (not sure if I need to or not).  My head tags

```
  <script src="js/headroom.min.js"></script>   
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // grab an element
    var myElement = document.querySelector("header");
    // construct an instance of Headroom, passing the element
    var headroom  = new Headroom(myElement);
    // initialise
    headroom.init();
</script>
```

My CSS for both the header and the pinned and unpinned:

```
header {width:100%;height:75px;background: #383838 url('../images/header-bg.png') repeat-x    left top;}
header.headroom {position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;transition: all .2s ease-in-out;}
header.headroom--unpinned {top: -75px;}
header.headroom--pinned {top: 0;}
```

My header does not have any classes, I am just using the header tag.

Right now my header is at the top of the page, unfixed.  I am fairly new to javascript and am probably missing something pretty obvious.  Please let me know if you can help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running the script at the top of the page, before the html is loaded, so the `header` element is not yet loaded. You need to either load this script at the bottom of the page, or to make it load on document complete.

Comment: I placed the script right before the end of the body tag and now it works.  Thank you so much, this was driving me nuts!

Comment: great to the point